# On delegate, event, evenhandler, in F#

Tags: excel, events, f#, constraints

If I look at [Control.IEvent<'Delegate,'Args>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340439.aspx), it imposes on `'Args` that

```
IEvent<'Delegate,'Args when 'Delegate : delegate<'Args,unit>...>
```

Looking at [WorkbookBase.NewSheet Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbookbase.newsheet.aspx), to which [WorkbookEvents_NewSheetEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookevents_newsheeteventhandler%28v=office.14%29.aspx), of type `obj-> unit`, can subscribe, I would have expected `'Args` to be of type `obj` in its F# type.

However, I see that the event `NewSheet` is of type `IEvent<WorkbookEvents_NewSheetEventHandler, unit>`

[image]
What can explain this ?

---

Adding the extract of the spec mentioned in the answer :

---

5.2.8     **Delegate Constraints**
An explicit delegate constraint has the following form:

typar : delegate

During constraint solving (§14.5), the constraint type : delegate is met if type is a delegate type D with declaration type D = delegate of **object *** arg1 * ... * argN and tupled-arg-type = arg1 * ... * argN. That is, the delegate must match the CLI design pattern where the sender object is the first argument to the event.

Note: This constraint form exists primarily to allow the definition of certain F# library functions that are related to event programming. It is rarely used directly in F# programming.

The delegate constraint does not imply anything about subtypes. In particular, a ‘delegate’ constraint does not imply that the type is a subtype of System.Delegate.

The delegate constraint applies only to delegate types that follow the usual form for CLI event handlers, where the first argument is a “sender” object. The reason is that the purpose of the constraint is to simplify the presentation of CLI event handlers to the F# programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [how the spec defines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818807) the delegate constraint: the `obj` sender argument is implicit.

Comment: do you know what would be the least intrusive way to get back the stream of obj * arg?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; could you elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve?